# Socket.io + Node.js CORS ERROR Blocked my req

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using node and socket.io to write an application, which gives an error to enable the Cross-Origin Requests.

```
const io = require("./socket").init(server, {
      cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      },
    });
```

This is my soket.io code...

```
    let io;
    module.exports = {
      init: (httpServer) => {
        io = require("socket.io")(httpServer);
        return io;
      },
      getIO: () => {
        if (!io) {
          throw new Error("Socket.io not inittialized");
        }
    return io;
  },
};
```

Help me out from this thanks in advance...

Comment: Let me see, I got it please follow my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in socket js you have to send

```
cors: {
       origin: "*",
       methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      },
```

Cors in the socket also to avoid this error

```
   let io;
    module.exports = {
      init: (httpServer) => {
        io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
          cors: {
            origin: "*",
            methods: ["GET", "POST"],
          },
        });
        return io;
      },
      getIO: () => {
        if (!io) {
          throw new Error("Socket.io not inittialized");
        }
        return io;
      },
    };
```

Hope it works for you...

Comment: ill try, i hope it works...